# How to structure a Python code: Functions, Classes, Modules ?

Tags: python, networkx

This is a question about how to better organize a Python code into functions/classes and modules. If you can explain what is the best way to organize your work, I would really appreciate it.

The code can be divided into 2 parts: Part 1 constructs a tree based on Networkx (DiGraph) and Part2 does some calculations on this tree's nodes, works recursively through its nodes and outputs a number.

A simplified version of the code:

```
a1 = 200; a2=250; n=50                       #Constants, User inputs
constantes =['x','y','z']                    #Constants calculated from User input
G=nx.DiGraph()                               #I initiate the graph
for step in range(0,n+1):
    if not current_step_nodes:
        current_step_nodes = ['a']
        G.add_nodes_from(current_step_nodes)
    else:
        for i in current_step_nodes:
            a=[i]
            for j in constantes:
                a.append(''.join(sorted(i + j)))
            G.add_edges_from(_tree_edges(a,3))
            a=[]
    current_step_nodes = [w for w in G.nodes() if len(w) == step]
```

So this builds a tree G that looks like for:

```
 For n=2: a->ax, a->ay, a->az
```

The next step: I add attributes 's1', and 's2' to each node of G.

```
for ns1 in G.nodes():
    G.node[ns1]['s1']=products1     #products1 are numbers calculated in the code
    G.node[ns1]['s2']=products2
```

----- This ends the tree, I wish I could save this and don't touch it again.

Part2 : Add an atribure 'value' and work recursively from the leafs:

```
for leafs in set(w for w in G.nodes() if len(w) == n):
    G.node[leafs]['value']=max(s1*G.node[leafs]['s1']-s2*G.node[leafs]['s2'],0)
for i in reversed(xrange(n)):
    nodes_in_i = [w for w in  G.nodes() if len(w) == i]
    for node in nodes_in_i:
        for succ in G.successors(node):
            G.node[node]['value']=G.node[node]['value']+G.node[succ]['value']
```

Ultimately I am interested in the value of 'value' at the root 'a'. Currently I have this code as part of a huge function named arbol(n), so I just:

```
return G.node['a']['value']
```

---- I now want to see how this 'value' changes when n increases:

```
def main(): 
    for n in xrange(8):
        print arbol(n)
```

---- The thing is now for example I want to do more stuff with this tree G like add more attributes and do other calculations like see how G.node['a']['value'] changes if the user input changes.

So ideally I would like to have this split into several files like: arbol.py, value.py, value_when_n_changes.py etc.

This is the way I think code should be organized. But I dont know how to structure this and code it (i.e. can this graph be a class? can G be an instance of this class? can I then change/add atributes of this graph G using functions?).

Thank you for your suggestions ! I am quite new at Python!

Comment: I think codereview.stackexchange.com is the place for such questions.

Comment: I'm not sure. I see codereview as a place to improve code. My code needs no review. I intended this as a question to learn how to structure code which is inherently a programming question and how can networkx graphs be used in functions/classes.